# Frame Processing on a live camera feed using JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built a simple JS web app that takes an passport image via upload and attempts to crop only the MRZ out of an passport image using image processing techniques in the image js module. However, the app I built only works on still images that are uploaded from the photo library or a phone taken from the camera.

How would I be able to run image processing on every frame from a live camera feed in the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the webcam component.
Install using npm:

```
npm install react-webcam
```

Install using yarn:

```
yarn add react-webcam
```

```js
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import { React, createRef } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() { 
  
  const ref = createRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={500}
        ref={ref}
        width={500}
      />

   </header>
  </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam)